# How to stress an AMD GPU to nearly 100% workload using minimal LOC in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, stream-processing

Out of curiosity I want to stress my HD5750 GPU to nearly 100% workload using OpenCL, how would I do this with minimal effort/code? Apparently the HD5750 has 720 stream processors, so I presume I have to do some parallel computational loop on all cores?

Comment: Yes, run some endless loop in parallel on your GPU (probably calculating something non-trivial; I don't know how good GPU compiler optimizations are, whether they'd remove trivial no-op loops).

Comment: stress both fpu and alu and special function units and local memory and don't forget constant memory it is fast (make all using thread level parallelism or maybe instruction level parallelism too). Use vectorized codes for vliw. don't copy buffers between executions